# Syncing android contacts with server

Tags: android, synchronization, android-contacts

I am creating an android app that keeps track of all contacts saved on the device (the ones that appear in the default android contacts app) and saves them in a MySQL table on the server.

I managed to read all contact data using `ContectResolver`:

```
    //to read only android address book
    String where = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'";

    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER};

    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, where, null, null);
```

Then, using the `ContactsContract.Contacts._ID` I query additional contact data:

```
// Perform a query to retrieve the contact's name parts
        String[] nameProjection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME
        };

        Cursor nameCursor = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                nameProjection,
                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND " +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTACT_ID
                        + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

        // Retrieve the name parts
        String firstName = "", middleName = "", lastName = "", displayName = "";
        if(nameCursor.moveToNext()) {
            firstName = nameCursor.getString(nameCursor.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
            middleName = nameCursor.getString(nameCursor.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME));
            lastName = nameCursor.getString(nameCursor.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
            displayName = nameCursor.getString(nameCursor.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
```

I then send all this data (including the contact's email addresses and phone numbers) to the server.

I want to be able to periodically backup the device's contacts like this, but to  be able to detect changes in contact data, by comparing the old data to the new data. But to do this, i need to have some sort of link between the contacts in the android device, and my DB in which i save the contact data.

After some searching i found 3 options:

```
ContactsContract.Contacts._ID
ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY
ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID
```

But from what I found, all of them are not reliable, and can change in certain situations - invalidating the link between my DB to the device's contact list.

I have considered the option to use `ContentObserver` to detect contact changes. But, I want to be able to detect contact changes even if my app has been uninstalled, then some contacts have changed and then my app has been reinstalled.

**Is there a reliable identification key per contact that I can use, to know when a certain contact has been changed or deleted?**

EDIT:

I now found this variable exists: `ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP`

The problem is that it was introduces only in API level 18. I am working on min API 15. Is there something that could replace it for the missing API levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid it is not possible to know if particular contact changed. Therefore you can register observer on whole address book URI. This way you will be able to listen when anything in address book changes.

Now having observer you can scan all contacts and perform "sync" data to your server.

In your particular case pair of ContactsContract.Contacts._ID and ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY should be reliable enough. But in order to know if anything changed you need either:

- send all contacts to server and perform sync logic on server (id and lookup key should be stored on MySQL)
- keep local copy of contacts on your device (sqllite db, realm, any other storage) in order to avoid unchanged contacts to be sent to server every time you sync

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i edited my question - found out about ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP.

In case i implement it the way you describe, how would you go about checking the ID and LOOKUP KEY on the server side? I mean, is it enough if only one matches, or is it possible that a new contact will get the same ID or LOOKUP KEY as a contact in the past?

Comment: If ID + LOOKUP KEY of contact change, it will not likely be the same as other contact. Therefore if you modify contact it is likely its LOOKUP KEY to be changed, so basically you are creating new contact and old one must be deleted